# fix transparent icons in non-supporting android phones

Tags: android, icons, transparent

I have created a transparent icon for my android app but it does not appear consistently in all phones. For example, in most phones the icon appears transparent but in my Xiaomi phone it looks very weird because Xiaomi does not support transparent icons. In Xiaomi, the transparent layer is turned black and since I'm using black color in my icon, it looks fudged.

I searched [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) but you can't differentiate resource based on phone models. What other options do I have?

I am uploading the icon for your benefit.

This is how my icon looks:
[image]

And this is how it looks on Xiaomi: [image]